# Is it possible to swap 'msg' for 'message' with logrus logging

Tags: go, logrus

So when using Logrus I need the logging output to have the `message` key instead of `msg` key, but when I use the code below I get both, but `msg` is empty,  how can I configure logrus to use 'message' instead of 'msg'?

```
contextLogger.WithField("logger_name",topic).WithField("message",messageString).Info()
```

Here's the log output when leaving `.Info()` empty // `.Info()` logs to the `msg` key

```
"logger_name": "logger","message": "log message","msg": "","time": "2020-08-12T15:14:48Z"
```

What I would like is to be able to use `.Info(message)` and have

```
"logger_name": "logger","message": "log message","time": "2020-08-12T15:14:48Z"
```

Is it possible to change default logging keys for .Info() etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do so using the `FieldMap` field of [JSonFormatter](https://godoc.org/github.com/sirupsen/logrus#JSONFormatter):

```golang
    // FieldMap allows users to customize the names of keys for default fields.
    // As an example:
    // formatter := &JSONFormatter{
    //      FieldMap: FieldMap{
    //       FieldKeyTime:  "@timestamp",
    //       FieldKeyLevel: "@level",
    //       FieldKeyMsg:   "@message",
    //       FieldKeyFunc:  "@caller",
    //    },
    // }
    FieldMap FieldMap
```

This allows you to override the default field names, including `msg`.

Here's a short example (see on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bBErCknozey)):

```golang
package main

import (
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFormatter(&log.JSONFormatter{
        FieldMap: log.FieldMap{
            log.FieldKeyMsg: "message",
        },
    })

    log.WithField("logger_name", "topic2").Info("this is my message")
}
```

Output:

```
{"level":"info","logger_name":"topic2","message":"this is my message","time":"2009-11-10T23:00:00Z"}
```

The same override is available on the [TextFormatter](https://godoc.org/github.com/sirupsen/logrus#TextFormatter).